# Bypassing http_proxy in Golang

Tags: go, proxy, http-proxy

I have env variable set for http_proxy, but with another call, I like to bypass proxy and use direct connection to destination server instead.

Is there any way I can do that in Go lang?

Thanks.

Comment: Just don't use the http.DefaultTransport: See https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper

Comment: awesome thanks Volker.

Answer (score 3):

As @Volker mentioned, you can either:

- Use your own [`RoundTripper`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) instead of the `DefaultTransport`
- Modify [`DefaultTransport.Proxy`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) to return nil for the request in question
- If the call you want to ignore proxies with is to a specific host, and you always want to ignore proxy for calls to that host, add the host to the [`NO_PROXY`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyFromEnvironment) environment variable

Answer (score 3):

this is what I did:

```
var defaultTransport http.RoundTripper = &http.Transport{
    Proxy: nil,
    DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        DualStack: true,
    }).DialContext,
    MaxIdleConns:          30,
    IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout:   15 * time.Second,
    ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
}

client := &http.Client{Transport: defaultTransport}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had that problem with a corporate proxy, even disabled the proxy url it was using it
this was my solution

```
// reset proxy in http RoundTripper
var defaultTransport http.RoundTripper = &http.Transport{Proxy: nil}
client := &http.Client{Transport: defaultTransport}
```